# Showing values of multiple related records in a continuous form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm very new to Access (doing some volunteer work with it), and am having trouble with displaying related information. I've worked with mySQL databases and am familiar with php/python scripting in that respect, but it seems that that doesn't translate well to Access. Here's what I have:

I have a table full of different locations that are monitored by a set of volunteers. This table holds info on the location's name, address, etc.

I have another table containing volunteer info (name, address, etc.) I am using a third assignment table to link this info, where I have a field for the location id, the volunteer id, and whether the assignment is still active.

My trouble comes in here. I'm trying to make a continuous form that has every location listed, but so that each record has an embedded list of volunteers with currently active assignments. Subforms won't work in a continuous form. I've tried listboxes, but I don't think this is their intended purpose. I can get the list of volunteers via listboxes, but it is all volunteers with any assignment. I need some way to get the parent record's location id. Additionally, I'd like clicking on one of these volunteer names to open up their specific record in a volunteer form.

I'm using Access 2007. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible options: 1. https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp 2. cascading (dependent) listbox, however doesn't work nicely on continuous or datasheet form with lookup alias